# On line email form hangs on php mail() function. What server issue could be causing this?

Tags: web-hosting, php, apache, email, webserver

I have a contact form on my website that has a dead simple php mail() function. I am 99% certain the php is not the issue as I have the exact same function on other sites that works fine.

However, when I try to use the form on one site in particular it seems to hang and not send the email and not redirect to the success page. Would anyone know what could be causing this on the server side?

If anyones interested my php is:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$message= $_REQUEST['message'] ;

$webmaster_email = "myemail@mysite.com";
$thankyou_page = "http://www.mysite.com/thanks-for-your-inquiry.html";

mail( "$webmaster_email", "Site Form", "From: noreply@mysite.com",
   "From: $email  \n 
    Name: $name \n
    Phone: $phone\n 
    Message: $message\n ");

header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
```

Comment: Does  noreply@mysite.com exist ? I had faced such an issue, and after creating  noreply@mysite.com, I was able to send mails.

Comment: @KutePHP no it doesnt exist. Ill try creating it. Thanks